# How to automate table's values use as arg in a function?

Tags: python

I have a function with two args: `Function (A, B):...`

In my function, arg must be paired and are actually registered within a table as shown:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Arg A1 | Arg B1 |
| Arg A2 | Arg B2 |

Is there a way to read the function with every line from the table without writing manually `function(Arg A1, Arg B1)`, `function(Arg A2,Arg B2 )` etc... ?

Where:

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```py
for (a,b) in zip(A,B):
   result = function(a,b)
   print(result)
```

This requires however that you have `A`and `B`as a list.